# Escaping MySQL UPDATE (IF LENGTH)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, addslashes

I've created an UPDATE statement that updates only if the string's length is greater than 0.

I'm trying to escape quotes within my UPDATE statement once the condition is met. I've been using `addslashes($name)`, but with this new condition `addslashes` no longer works.

Previous:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET name='".addslashes($name)."' WHERE id=1") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Current:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET name=IF(LENGTH($name)=0, name, '$name') WHERE id=1") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Where do I place `addslashes()` for this function to correctly escape characters? Will this function even work within this particular MySQL statement for PHP?

Comment: You would be better off doing this in PHP (check string length and don't run the update if not needed).  It would also be worth looking at prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your second query is that `$name` inside the call to `LENGTH` needs to be in quotes too i.e.

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET name=IF(LENGTH('$name')=0, name, '$name') WHERE id=1") or die($mysqli->error);
```

To use `addslashes` in that query, you would write:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET name=IF(LENGTH('".addslashes($name)."')=0, name, '".addslashes($name)."') WHERE id=1") or die($mysqli->error);
```

But really you should consider using a prepared statement instead; then you won't have to worry about escaping quotes. Additionally, you should check the length of `$name` in PHP and not run the query at all if it is empty.  Something like this should work (I'm assuming you have a variable called `$id` which stores the id value for the update).

```
if (strlen($name)) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET name=? WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $name, $id);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
}
```

If you have multiple pieces of data to update, you could try something like this:

```
$name = 'fred';
$city = '';
$state = 'SA';
$id = 4;
$params = array();
foreach (array('name','city','state') as $param) {
    if (strlen($$param)) $params[$param] = $$param;
}
$sql = "UPDATE table SET " . implode(' = ?, ', array_keys($params)) . " = ? WHERE id = ?";
$types = str_repeat('s', count($params)) . 'i';
$params['id'] = $id;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
```

Comment: Hey thanks, Nick. If I wanted to check more values within a row (for empty strings), such as 'city' or 'state', would I have to create an IF statement for each variable and then bind every variable? How would you go about efficiently checking string lengths and updating multiple variables with one UPDATE query?

Comment: @JoshuaN see my edit. I think that is probably the most efficient way of doing what you want